# pexpect: How to interact() over file object using newer version of pexpect library

Tags: python, serial-port, pexpect

`pexpect` has gone through big changes since the version provided by Ubuntu 15.04 (3.2). When installing newest version of `pexpect`  using `pip3`, this minimal program that previously successfully gave terminal emulation over serial console does not work any more:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import serial
import pexpect.fdpexpect

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=115200)
spawn = pexpect.fdpexpect.fdspawn(ser)
spawn.interact()
```

The newer API is missing interact() method in class `pexpect.fdpexpect.fdspawn` which used to be there.

**Question:** how is the newer version of pexpect (currently 4.2.1) supposed to be used to provide free manual interaction with file object (serial port in this case)?

**Alternatively, question/work-around**: I recognize I am using a bit heavy machinery for such a simple use case, any suggestions for other python libraries that can do the same as earlier version of pexpect could?

---

Code reading: Examples use `pexpect.spawn(command_str)` to get a `spawn` object which has `interact()` method; actually this `pexpect.spawn()` is the same as directly creating a `pexpect.pty_spawn.spawn` object which has this method. On the other hand, `pexpect.fdpexpect.fdspawn()` will construct a `pexpect.fdpexpect.fdspawn` class which is missing `interact()` method. Both of these spawn classes derive from `pexpect.spawnbase.SpawnBase` class. Based on my quick reading, this looks like regression that resulted from refactoring on the way to version 4.x.

Answer (score 0):

Browsing the [pexpect](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect) [issues](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues), found [#351](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/351), [#356](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/356), and the newly submitted [#377](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/377). By my quick reading, it seems this is a regression that was brought by uncompleted refactoring along the way towards new major release version 4. There are three possible avenues:

1. Make sure to install older version:

   $ pip3 install "pexpect<3"

   (or make sure that the version installed by other system is 3.x).
2. Fix `pexpect` by yourself.
3. Use some other python library.

These avenues were all more or less hinted by github user @takluyver, apparently maintainer of `pexpect` in comment to issue #351:

> @jquast any thoughts on what to do for this (and #356)? I feel bad that we've broken things people were doing with fdspawn, but I really don't want to make it inherit from the pty spawn class, and now that it works on Windows, I think it's important to preserve that too.
>
> Maybe we should just say:
>
> - If you have legacy code that broke with Pexpect 4, downgrade to Pexpect 3.x (`pip install pexpect<4`)
> - If you're writing new code, use [streamexpect](https://github.com/digidotcom/python-streamexpect) instead of pexpect.